# Dart2JS Cannot Find Import Packages WebStorm

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-pub, dart2js

I am using the WebStorm 8 IDE to build a dart web app. I have the following directory structure:

```
root
   web
      main.dart
   lib
   packages
      browser
      intl
         intl.dart
   pubspec.lock
   pubspec.yaml
```

In `main.dart` I have the following import statment: `import "package:intl/intl.dart";`

However when I try and compile `main.dart` to javascript I get the following error:

```
dart2js
Error occurred:
/Path/To/Project/root/web/main.dart:2:8:
Error: Can't read 'package:intl/intl.dart' (Error reading '/Path/To/Project/root/web/packages/intl/intl.dart' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)).
import "package:../packages/intl/intl.dart";
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

So it seems that dart2js looks in the current directory of the dart file to be converted for the packages, which is incorrect.

I tried changing my import statement to `import "package:../packages/intl/intl.dart";` but I got the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE:

I can use `pub build` to build my project and produce a `main.dart.js`. Not sure what is different when I call build, perhaps something is wrong with WebStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong. I think this is one of the cases where only

```
pub cache repair
```

can help.

Comment: What are you using dart2js for anyway? use `pub build` for transpiling to JavaScript.

Comment: Sure I can use `pub build` but should dart2js should work by itself no?

Comment: Yes but `dart2js` is a bit more difficult to use (needs several arguments) and `pub build` is super easy and normally does all you want. If `pub build` works and `dart2js` not you have very probably called it from the wrong directory or passed wrong arguments.

Answer (score 1):

dart2js is not a recommended workflow and can be buggy in WebStorm 8. It is completely removed from the context menu in the upcoming WebStorm 9. Use 'pub build'.

Comment: Didn't know WebStorm 8 offers a menu for that.